# What alternatives are there to these switch statements?

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

Just whipped up this extremely simple GPA calculator, wondering how I would use a loop to avoid the huge blocks of switch statements? I am very new to Java and just looking for some advice, any other ways to improve the program are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance, guys!

```
package helloPackage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GradePointAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the GPA calculator! Please enter your GPA into the popup window to find your GPA.");

    String firstClassInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your grade for your first class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String firstClass = firstClassInput.toUpperCase();
    String secondClassInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your grade for your second class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String secondClass = secondClassInput.toUpperCase();
    String thirdClassInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your grade for your third class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String thirdClass = thirdClassInput.toUpperCase();
    String fourthClassInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your grade for your fourth class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String fourthClass = fourthClassInput.toUpperCase();
    String fifthClassInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your grade for your fifth class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String fifthClass = fifthClassInput.toUpperCase();

    double firstGrade = 0.0;
    double secondGrade = 0.0;
    double thirdGrade = 0.0;
    double fourthGrade = 0.0;
    double fifthGrade = 0.0;

    switch (firstClass){
    case "A+": firstGrade = 4.33;
        break;
    case "A": firstGrade = 4.00;
        break;
    case "A-": firstGrade = 3.67;
        break;
    case "B+": firstGrade = 3.33;
        break;
    case "B": firstGrade = 3.00;
        break;
    case "B-": firstGrade = 2.67;
        break;
    case "C+": firstGrade = 2.33;
        break;
    case "C": firstGrade = 2.00;
        break;
    case "C-": firstGrade = 1.67;
        break;
    case "D+": firstGrade = 1.33;
        break;
    case "D": firstGrade = 1.00;
        break;
    case "D-": firstGrade = .67;
        break;
    case "F": firstGrade = 0.0;
        break;
    }

    switch (secondClass){
    case "A+": secondGrade = 4.33;
        break;
    case "A": secondGrade = 4.00;
        break;
    case "A-": secondGrade = 3.67;
        break;
    case "B+": secondGrade = 3.33;
        break;
    case "B": secondGrade = 3.00;
        break;
    case "B-": secondGrade = 2.67;
        break;
    case "C+": secondGrade = 2.33;
        break;
    case "C": secondGrade = 2.00;
        break;
    case "C-": secondGrade = 1.67;
        break;
    case "D+": secondGrade = 1.33;
        break;
    case "D": secondGrade = 1.00;
        break;
    case "D-": secondGrade = .67;
        break;
    case "F": secondGrade = 0.0;
        break;
    }
    switch (thirdClass){
    case "A+": thirdGrade = 4.33;
        break;
    case "A": thirdGrade = 4.00;
        break;
    case "A-": thirdGrade = 3.67;
        break;
    case "B+": thirdGrade = 3.33;
        break;
    case "B": thirdGrade = 3.00;
        break;
    case "B-": thirdGrade = 2.67;
        break;
    case "C+": thirdGrade = 2.33;
        break;
    case "C": thirdGrade = 2.00;
        break;
    case "C-": thirdGrade = 1.67;
        break;
    case "D+": thirdGrade = 1.33;
        break;
    case "D": thirdGrade = 1.00;
        break;
    case "D-": thirdGrade = .67;
        break;
    case "F": thirdGrade = 0.0;
        break;
    }
    switch (fourthClass){
    case "A+": fourthGrade = 4.33;
        break;
    case "A": fourthGrade = 4.00;
        break;
    case "A-": fourthGrade = 3.67;
        break;
    case "B+": fourthGrade = 3.33;
        break;
    case "B": fourthGrade = 3.00;
        break;
    case "B-": fourthGrade = 2.67;
        break;
    case "C+": fourthGrade = 2.33;
        break;
    case "C": fourthGrade = 2.00;
        break;
    case "C-": fourthGrade = 1.67;
        break;
    case "D+": fourthGrade = 1.33;
        break;
    case "D": fourthGrade = 1.00;
        break;
    case "D-": fourthGrade = .67;
        break;
    case "F": fourthGrade = 0.0;
        break;
    }
    switch (fifthClass){
    case "A+": fifthGrade = 4.33;
        break;
    case "A": fifthGrade = 4.00;
        break;
    case "A-": fifthGrade = 3.67;
        break;
    case "B+": fifthGrade = 3.33;
        break;
    case "B": fifthGrade = 3.00;
        break;
    case "B-": fifthGrade = 2.67;
        break;
    case "C+": fifthGrade = 2.33;
        break;
    case "C": fifthGrade = 2.00;
        break;
    case "C-": fifthGrade = 1.67;
        break;
    case "D+": fifthGrade = 1.33;
        break;
    case "D": fifthGrade = 1.00;
        break;
    case "D-": fifthGrade = .67;
        break;
    case "F": fifthGrade = 0.0;
        break;
    }

    double total = firstGrade + secondGrade + thirdGrade + fourthGrade + fifthGrade;  
    double GPA = total / 5;
    System.out.println("Your GPA is: " + GPA);
}
```

}

Comment: Since when is an A+ a 4.33

Comment: In which country have GPA 4.33?

Comment: You can use a map which would link each letter grade to it's double value. Then you can iterate through each key in the map and when you hit a match, use the value at that key.

Comment: Why did you need multiple switches in the first place?  Why couldn't you do all the assignments in just one?

Comment: Because I'm a noob and don't know what I'm doing! =P Oh and I just went by http://web.williams.edu/admin/registrar/records/gpa.html. This is just for practice guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a method like `double getGrade(String)` as follows

```
double firstGrade = getGrade(firstClass);
double secondGrade = getGrade(secondClass);
double thirdGrade = getGrade(thirdClass);
double fourthGrade = getGrade(fourthClass);
double fifthGrade = getGrade(fifthClass);

// Use your switch statement.... no break(s) because we return.
public static double getGrade(String grade) {
  switch (grade){
  case "A+": return 4.33;
  case "A": return 4.00;
  case "A-": return 3.67;
  case "B+": return 3.33;
  case "B": return 3.00;
  case "B-": return 2.67;
  case "C+": return 2.33;
  case "C": return 2.00;
  case "C-": return 1.67;
  case "D+": return 1.33;
  case "D": return 1.00;
  case "D-": return .67;
  }
  // F
  return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: This solution is more tailored to my personal understanding of Java, which is basically none compared to everyone on here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily create an Enum to represent those grade and put the value of the grade as field within the enum.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having `firstGrade`, `secondgrade`, etc., use an array or List:

```
double[] grades = new double[5]; // firstGrade will be grades[0], and so on.
```

For the letter grades, I suggest using enums, with the `valueOf()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This method removes all switches, and only uses two if statements:

```
public static double getGrade(String grade) {
  double retVal = 0.0;
  char letter = grade.getCharAt(0); //Get the letter grade

  //Compute the base grade--some of these casts may not be needed 
  //(I'm not figuring it out right now)
  retVal = Math.max((int)'A' - (int)letter + 4, 0.0);

  if (grade.length() == 1) return retVal;

  //Alter the grade based on the postfix
  char pm = grade.getCharAt(1); //Get the plus/minus

  if (pm == '+') retVal += 0.33;
  else           retVal -= 0.33;

  return retVal;
}
```

Then, use the array approach mentioned in "Chthonic Project"'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one large switch statement.

Instead of having firstClass/firstGrade/secondClass/secondGrade, just have two arrays, class[] and grade[]. Then you can do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    switch(class[i]){
         case "A+" : grade[i] = 4.33;
    }
 }
```

Comment: That's still a lot of case statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you encapsulate some of the similar tasks to separate methods, it should make your code a little cleaner. try this.Hope this helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out
            .println("Welcome to the GPA calculator! Please enter your GPA into the popup window to find your GPA.");

    String firstClassInput = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter your grade for your first class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String firstClass = firstClassInput.toUpperCase();
    String secondClassInput = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter your grade for your second class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String secondClass = secondClassInput.toUpperCase();
    String thirdClassInput = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter your grade for your third class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String thirdClass = thirdClassInput.toUpperCase();
    String fourthClassInput = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter your grade for your fourth class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String fourthClass = fourthClassInput.toUpperCase();
    String fifthClassInput = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog(null,
                    "Please enter your grade for your fifth class: (A+, A, A-, B+, etc.)");
    String fifthClass = fifthClassInput.toUpperCase();

    List<String> listOfGrades = new ArrayList<String>();
    listOfGrades.add(firstClass);
    listOfGrades.add(secondClass);
    listOfGrades.add(thirdClass);
    listOfGrades.add(fourthClass);
    listOfGrades.add(fifthClass);

    double GPA = getGPA( listOfGrades );
    System.out.println("Your GPA is: " + GPA);
}


/**
 * Used to calculate GPA from list of supplied grades
 * 
 * @param listOfGrades as list of grades to compute GPA
 * @return GPA as double
 */
public static double getGPA(List<String> listOfGrades){
    double total = 0.0;
    double GPA = 0.0;

    for(String aGrade: listOfGrades){
         total += getGrade( aGrade );

    }
    GPA = total / listOfGrades.size();
    System.out.println("Total "+total+" amount of grades: "+listOfGrades.size());
    return GPA;
}

/**
 * Get value of grade as a double type
 * 
 * @param stringGrade Grade
 * @return value of grade as 
 */
public static double getGrade(String stringGrade ){

    double grade = 0.0;
    switch (stringGrade) {
    case "A+":
        grade = 4.33;
        break;
    case "A":
        grade = 4.00;
        break;
    case "A-":
        grade = 3.67;
        break;
    case "B+":
        grade = 3.33;
        break;
    case "B":
        grade = 3.00;
        break;
    case "B-":
        grade = 2.67;
        break;
    case "C+":
        grade = 2.33;
        break;
    case "C":
        grade = 2.00;
        break;
    case "C-":
        grade = 1.67;
        break;
    case "D+":
        grade = 1.33;
        break;
    case "D":
        grade = 1.00;
        break;
    case "D-":
        grade = .67;
        break;
    case "F":
        grade = 0.0;
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("stringGrade: "+stringGrade+"="+grade);
    return grade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using either a **Enum** or a **Map**, mostly since there are the most human readable alternatives and it also gives you a good opportunity to decouple the data from the UI/Logic layer.

Example Enum:

```
public enum Grades {
    APLUS("A+", 4.33),
    A("A",4.00);

    private String label;
    private double value;
    private Grades(String label,double value){
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Grades getByLabel(String label){
        for(Grades grades : values()){
            if(grades.label.equals(label)){
                return grades;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect Label");
    }

}
```

Later used in your code with `Grades.getByLabel(firstGrade).getValue();`
Enum is very good if you plan on adding any extra data that is connected to each grade. Some other kind of measurement or similar, then there is no need for several arrays, lists or similar.

Example Map (in a separate class):

```
public class GradeValues {
private static Map<String,Double> gradeValues = new HashMap<String, Double>();
static{
    gradeValues.put("A+", 4.33);
    gradeValues.put("A", 4.00);
}

public static double getGradeValue(String grade){
    return gradeValues.get(grade);
}
```

}

Later used in your code with:

```
GradeValues.getGradeValue(firstGrade);
```