# I think I'm using IF statements wrongly

Tags: java, if-statement

So I'm trying to make a GPA calculator using Java and I'm stuck on one of the first steps. I'm trying to write a code that takes the input of the user and then converts it into a number, I will then use that number later on to calculate the GPA. Here's my code so far:

```
public class data {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String english;
        double v1 = 0;


        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your english grade");
        english= reader.nextLine();

        if (strcmp(english,"A+")==0) {
            v1 = 4.4;
        }

        if (strcmp(english,"A")==0) {   
            v1= 4.0;
        }
        if (strcmp(english,"A-")==0) {  
            v1= 3.6;
        }

        if (strcmp(english,"B+")==0) {  
            v1= 3.4;
        }

        if (strcmp(english,"B")==0) {   
            v1= 3;
        }
        if (strcmp(english,"B-")==0) {  
            v1= 2.6;
        }
        if (strcmp(english,"C+")==0) {  
            v1= 2.4;
        }
        if (strcmp(english,"C")==0) {   
            v1= 2;
        }
        if (strcmp(english,"C-")==0) {  
            v1= 1.6;
        }
        if (strcmp(english,"D+")==0) {  
            v1= 1.4;
        }
        if (strcmp(english,"D")==0){    
            v1= 1;
        }

        if (strcmp(english,"D-")==0) {  
            v1= 0.6;
        }
        if (strcmp(english,"F")==0) {   
            v1= 0.0;
        }
        else {

            v1=0.0;
        }


        System.out.println(v1);
```

As you can see, Im printing out V1 at the end just for checking, But it keeps giving V1 as 0.0, the value when the user enters "F". If I comment that piece of the code like this:

```
/*if (strcmp(english,"F")==0) { 
            v1= 0.0;
        }*/
```

then the output value it gives is 0.6, the value when the user enters D-. I think I'm supposed to put a return system somewhere? Although I really am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(If it wasn't established already, I am a beginner to java :P )

EDIT: Guys when I try to use the Switch method (Im using eclipse) it gives me this error: "Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted". The solution it provides then leads to further complications so I'd like to avoid switch statements :/

Comment: what is strcmp method doing?

Comment: better use switch or use ifelse it will reduce comparisons

Comment: Instead of using strcmp, you can use java's .equals method. For example, you can put down english.equals("F"),  which returns true if they are equal and false if they are not.

Comment: strcmp is string comparison ! its a c ! in java you can use .equals to test 2 strings

Comment: @almasshaikh, A friend told me to use it with if statements when im  working with strings rather than integers, if i used a normal if statement, it didnt work.

Comment: +1, if anything for *admitting* that the misuse is probably down to you rather than saying something like "Java `if` bug". Shows you're hunting for the bug in the correct way.

Comment: Thanks for the Help guys! I'm pretty sure all your methods would have worked, I (being new) opted for the easy one :(

Comment: Same task, possibly different question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20941509/1110928  There's some other approaches; I wrote one that avoids the massive if/then clauses altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this quite useful:

```
if(english.equalsIgnoreCase("A+"))
 //do stuff...
else if(english.equalsIgnoreCase("A-"))
  //do other stuff and so on...
```

the `equalsIgnoreCase()` method ignores case sensitive, if this is not what you're looking for you might try `equals()` instead.

The new Java version also introduced switch-case for Strings too so your code can become this one:

```
switch(english){
case "A+":
    //do stuff...
    break;
case "A-":
    //do other stuff... and so on...
    break;
}
```

Comment: YES! the equalsIgnoreCase() helped a lot as well! Thank you! :D

Comment: It seems to me it's not the equalsIgnoreCase that worked but rather the "else if".

Answer (score 7):

```
    if (strcmp(english,"F")==0) {   
        v1= 0.0;
    }
    else {

        v1=0.0;
    }
```

with that else you say - as long as it is not F, put 0.0 in v1.

Answer (score 5):

The way you've written it, `v1` will be 0.0 unless `english` is `"F"`.

You need to use `else if`:

```
if (strcmp(english,"A+")==0) {
    v1 = 4.4;
} else if (strcmp(english,"A")==0) {  
     // and so on
```

Some Java folk like to `switch` on strings. But that's a reasonably new feature in Java and the `break` statements that you'll need to introduce can obfuscate.

Answer (score 3):

use `switch` case, as mentioned. It will be helpful as you may get confused with large number of `if` statements.

```
switch(english){
  case "A+":
   v1=4.4
  break;

  case "D-":
   v1=0.6
  break;

  default:
   v1=0.0;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the breaks. Otherwise the result will always be 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last else part. it should be good.It is because no matter what the grade is, if it is not "F", it is going to the else statement and setting it to 0.0

Answer (score 0):

An `else` attaches to the previous `if`; you do a lot of stuff and then at the end you do `if(...) { v1 = 0.0 } else { v1 = 0.0 }`, setting the value to 0.0 in any case.

You might want to use `else if` at every step, which will solve the immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying if string is not F, set the value of v1= 0.0

```
if(strcmp(english,"F")==0) {   
        v1= 0.0;
    }
    else {

        v1=0.0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String english= reader.nextLine();
if (english.equals("A+")) {
    v1 = 4.4;
}
else if (english.equals("A")) {   
    v1= 4.0;
}
else if (english.equals("A-")) {  
    v1= 3.6;
}
else{
    v1=0.0;
}
```

Comment: Ive never seen this before, But it worked! :D I'm Guessing this basically means 
if english is equal to = x {
//do blah
}
and not adding the else if's was totally my fault, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are setting the value to zero whether the user enters F, or anything else:

```
    if (strcmp(english,"F")==0) {   
        v1= 0.0;
    }
    else {

        v1=0.0;
    }
```

see here, you've set `v1` to 0.0 `if (strcmp(english,"F")==0)`, but also if the user didn't enter F. I think you meant to put something else in stead of 0.0 in the if part, like this:

```
    if (strcmp(english,"F")==0) {   
        v1= /*something else*/;
    }
    else {

        v1=0.0;
    }
```

because that's what seemed to surprise you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code strcmp(english,"F")==0  with following  english.equal ("A+")